# sendkeys.Send - Failing suddenly after being run many times - Error - Access Denied - RDP .net

Tags: vb.net, automation, rdp

.net Automated task is hosted in a server that I connect through RDP.

Sending keys to a windows application(Not web browser)
`SendKeys.send` is working fine for a few runs and suddenly giving an error as  `Access denied - 0x80004005`

When I login and then trigger the task it's working fine. Also when the server is idle task is performing well until a few runs.

Comment: is there a screen saver or timed lockout of the machine that you are remoting into?  If yes,would it be it is working only when the device is not locked out / screen saver off?

Comment: yes, though disconnecting from the rdp, the scheduled code seems like running fine untill that user logged off due to timeout.

Comment: is there a way to prevent user logoff for rdp sessions? i have tried changing RDP session host timelimit settings and all on group policy (Windows server 2016), they didnt work though